# Use recursion to find longest path to leaf node inside binary tree with the three as a parameter

Tags: java, algorithm, height, binary-tree

I am self-studying for an exam and have run into a problem due to lack of examples & answers. An exercise states the following:

"Write an algorithm that uses recursion to calculate the height of a given binary tree, ie. the longest existing path from the root node to a leaf node."

A primitive start for a method is given, and this method must be modified to form the final answer. No additional methods are allowed outside this method:

```
// Binary tree height, find the longest path to a leaf node
public static int height(BTree t) {
    return 0;
}
```

A node is added to the tree before each call of the function.
The final given tree looks like this:

```
       10        
    __/  \__     
   5        15   
  / \      /  \  
 3   8   12    18
  \      /\      
   4    11 13
```

The following is what I have so far but it does not work properly:

```
// Binary tree height, find the longest path to a leaf node
public static int height(BTree t) {

    BTreeNode n = t.getRoot();

    int height = 0;
    int calc = 0;

    if (n == null)
    {
        return height;
    }
    else
    {
        while (n!=null) {
            n = n.getLeftChild();
            calc++;
        }
    }

    if(calc > height) {
        height = calc-1;
        height = 0;
    }

    n = t.getRoot();
    while (n!=null) {
        n = n.getRightChild();
        calc++;
    }

    if(calc > height) {
        height = calc-1;
        height = 0;
    }


    return height;
}  // height()
```

Please help me study for and pass the exam, all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean "a node is added before each call"? Does this mean that the tree is not already built?

Comment: I think you should have researched before asking this question. Height of a tree is a standard problem.

Comment: Yes, the tree is not built beforehand, but a node is added to the tree before each call of the function. In other words, on the first call the tree has only the root node and then this function is called from a separate main function to check the current height of the tree. I have researched, but have not found what to do in this situation where I am not allowed another recursive function, and the fact that this one gets the whole tree as a parameter, instead of a single node. I have spent the better part of two hours on this problem and am at a loss.

Comment: are you sure you aren't misreading the problem? this seems pretty odd. if each time the function gets called it adds a node, can't you just count the times the function gets called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, recursion would be a good choice. To get the height you start with the the root node and the depth 0. The you have a function to get the maximum depth. This function just returns the depth if the node passed to it is null (end of the tree). Otherwise it calls itself with the depth increased by 1 (there is another layer, hence the depth must be increased) for the left and right child. Then it returns the higher depth found. The code would look something like this:

```
public static int getMaxDepth(BTreeNode node, int depth) {
    if (node == null) return depth;
    return Math.max(getMaxDepth(node.getLeftChild(), depth + 1), getMaxDepth(node.getRightChild(), depth + 1));
}
```

This will walk through the whole tree and find the longest path.
(I did not test this code, but it should work.)

You can avoid `Math.max()` if you want with a simple if clause, which checks which depth is greater, but I personally prefer this way.

You can also try to resolve the recursion and replace it with iteration. But then you will have to write a lot more code, which will be harder to read and understand. One way without recursion would be to keep track of all the nodes in the current layer (and its depth) (e.g. with an ArrayList) and then get all the children of the nodes in the last layer. After that you update the list with the found children and increment your depth. if the list of children is empty, you have reached the end of the tree and can return the depth. The code to do this would look like this (again untested):

```
public static int getMaxDepth(BTreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) return 0;
    List<BTreeNode> currentLayer = new ArrayList<>();
    List<BTreeNode> children = new ArrayList<>();
    int depth = 0;

    currentLayer.add(root);
    while (0 < currentLayer.size()) {
        depth++;

        children.clear();
        for (BTreeNode node : currentLayer) {
            BTreeNode left = node.getLeftChild();
            if (left != null) children.add(left);

            BTreeNode right = node.getRightChild();
            if (right != null) children.add(right);
        }

        currentLayer.clear();
        currentLayer.addAll(children);
    }

    return depth;
}
```

Comment: This is what I would have done myself, but the exercise states that I am not allowed to write additional functions; instead the given function skeleton must be modified to solve the problem.

Comment: Well than recursion isn't really an option anymore as you can't create the required function. But you can use the second code snippet I posted and just use the code from the function. You just have to set the root variable to the root node of the tree.

Comment: Thank you for the help! The second code snippet works with a little modification, even though this is still not recursive like the exercise demanded. Marked as answered.

Comment: You are welcome. If you really need/want to use recursion while keeping the signature of the function the only way I see is to use the same algorithm as in the first snippet, but pass a tree as parameter, perform all actions on the root node of that tree and, when doing the recursive calls, to create a new tree with the left/right child as root node. This would work but would create many unnecessary tree instances.

Comment: This kept bugging me so I had to contact the original teacher of the course and asked him for an answer. He told me that it was in fact not stated that I was not allowed to create additional methods to implement recursion. Thus, the answer was to have the method skeleton call the first code snippet that you posted. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
public int height(BTree t) {

     if(t == null) {
          return 0;
     }

     return 1 + Math.max(height(t.left), height(t.right));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not seem to work. This is probably because the function gets the whole tree as a parameter instead of a BTreeNode. Thus, the t.left and t.right show errors.

Comment: can you just call this on t.getRoot()?